# How can I get back to my original git branch

Tags: git

I have a git repository. 
When I do 'git branch', it said

```
 $ git branch
* com-2.1-SS
```

and then I do 'git log', i get a list of my commit

```
$ git log
commit ff878926b78614e8bf6af161da06070618e9ff6b

commit 3ffda8cec60a74a718fb25fb7a9fe4b3c4381137

commit bf6bb3427d8031d8e172c3b8b7909c8580e929cd
```

So I want to check out my repository to 3ffda8cec. So I did 'git checkout 3ffda8cec'.

So far so good. It works and I get want I want.

But my question is how can I get back to com-2.1-SS?
i.e. reverse the fact that I 'git checkout 3ffda8cec'

When I do 'git branch', it said

```
$ git branch
* (no branch)
```

When I do 'git checkout git checkout  com-2.1-SS

```
error: pathspec 'com-2.1-SS' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Comment: Can you double check your output. Your original branch output said you have exactly one branch (`com-2.1-SS`) but your second git output says you have no branches at all but nothing you've said you've done should have wiped out your branches. The command that should work is `git checkout com-2.1-SS`, not `git checkout git checkout com-2.1-SS1`.

Comment: As @CharlesBailey said, it seems that between your two calls to `git branch` you removed the branch named `com-2.1-SS` (if you have used only git commands, you probably have used `git branch -D com-1.2-ss`) this is the most sensible explanation for your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[git reflog](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html) will show you the different values a branch tip had and you can checkout it to go back to a previous state.

Your case is easier since you still know now that the sha1 of `com-2.1-SS` before the `git checkout` was `ff878926b78614e8bf6af161da06070618e9ff6b` (which is basically what `git reflog` do) so you can directly do:

```
git checkout ff878926b78614e8bf6af161da06070618e9ff6b
```

Althoug I don't understand from your description at which point your branch was deleted, you can recreate your branch after the checkout with:

```
git checkout -b com-2.1-SS
```

Comment: No that your answer is wrong, but AFAICT the OP here just checked out `3ffda8cec` without removing `com-2.1-SS` (headless mode) and seems to not be able to checkout `com-2.1-SS` again. I'm not sure that reflog helps with anything here. But in the end, doing a `git checkout -B com-2.1-SS ff878926b` should indeed solve the issue.

Comment: I did not delect the branch. I don't understand why it is 'gone' after I check out to a SHA.